# Write over the border, even when the next cell has an empty String ("")

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to realize a Time sheet where you can see the workload.

It should look like that:

[image]

In this row, my code is just in the first Cell of the week, so it works just fine.

```
=WENN(UND($K8=AE$4;$P8<>"");(TEXT($P8;"##%"));"")
```

But of course its not usual to start all tasks at the first day of the week, so i would like to have this code in every Cell.
But because of the *empty String* i insert if the formula is not true, my insert doesn't write over his cellborder any more:

[image]

Is there any possibility in Formula, or the formatting to solve this problem?

thx

Comment: No. Unless the cell is *empty* the adjacent cell contents cannot overlap it

Comment: can you not just leave the cell empty? if i wrtie:
(TEXT($P8;"##%"));) instead of (TEXT($P8;"##%"));""), in the cell is a 0 and its not empty...

Comment: Unfortunately not. A cell with a formula in it can never be truly empty. (there is still no equivalent of the DAX BLANK() function sadly)

Comment: @Rory So is there no way to solve this problem?
or an alternativ way?

Comment: You could use code to insert the formula only to the cells that are appropriate, or even use a UDF to position textboxes on the sheet. The former is probably simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, not very nice, but it works...
I wrote the formula just in the first cell of a week and did the formatting with some extra space, to get the insert to the right place.

I know, not a very good solution but i had to help myself.

```
=WENN(UND($K6<=Q$4;$K6>=Q$4-2;$P6<>"");(TEXT($P6;"##%"));
WENN(UND($K6=Q$4+1;$P6<>"");"    " &TEXT($P6;"##%");
WENN(UND($K6=Q$4+2;$P6<>"");"        " &TEXT($P6;"##%");
WENN(UND($K6=Q$4+3;$P6<>"");"            " &TEXT($P6;"##%");
WENN(UND($K6=Q$4+4;$P6<>"");"                " &TEXT($P6;"##%");"")))))
```

maybe for someone else who also has to fight with excel formatting.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

right click the cells and in Format cells-->Alignment--->check the "Shrink to fit" under Text Control